# getting authorized then post data c# winforms

Tags: c#, post, httpclient

I have a winform application in c#. I want to make HTTPRequest then post username and password to get authorized and use this authorization to post data to another page on the website that`is a image of second page i want to post data to from TamperData addon

http://postimg.org/image/9c01ime1t/

when I try to post data to it it gives me Internal Server Error 500 So I think exception because of authorization.

Comment: A 500 error doesn't provide much information.  Is there a more specific error message in the response?  If you've replicated the HTTP requests that the server expects, there isn't much you can do with a 500 error other than report it to the server's admin.

Comment: It`s secret method to connect to server I can`t connect to server admin to tell him that

Comment: If the server genuinely doesn't *support* what you're trying to do, that may be a factor worth considering in the error you're encountering.